# Answer no longer linked to my account after being migrated twice?

Tags: support, answers, migration

I recently answered [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139911/construct-context-free-grammar-for-the-language) which was originally asked on Stack Overflow.  I asked for it to be migrated to math.stackexchange, but it was accidentally migrated to Mathematica.  From there, it was moved to Mathematics.

I don't have a Mathematica account, so when the question was migrated back to Mathematics (where I do have an account), the question was no longer linked to my main account and doesn't show up under my list of answers.

Is this deliberate?  Is this a bug?  Is there a way I can get that question added back to my account?  I'm not interested in the rep points as much as being able to more easily pull this answer up if I find something similar later on.

Comment: That's an interesting case.  I think bad migrations like that are supposed to be reversed, so probably this was never planned for.